# Accountless password generation

Tags: customization, database, password

I want page1 to have a button/link. When the visitor clicks it, he gets a random password like "a84f20". And I want to save this password.
How to approach this? I can program but I don't know wordpress at all.

*The visitor shouldn't have to open an account or input any information about himself.

I'll provide my next step for background, but it's out of scope for the question:
In order to enter page2, the visitor will need a password that was generated at least 60 hours ago.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you want this pseudo-account to integrate into the rest of the site, e.g. should it work with the comment system or the admin site? That will influence whether you store these as WordPress accounts or not. If not, you'll probably want a new database table for your users.

Comment: I don't need it to integrate with the rest of the site. Yeah, a new table sounds good